# Is this convergence error?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

```
Integrate[(1 - (-Gamma[γ/ξ, -((p λ)/ξ)] + 
 Gamma[γ/ξ, (p (-1 + z) λ)/ξ])/(
Gamma[γ/ξ] - Gamma[γ/ξ, -((
   p λ)/ξ)])) z^(μ/ξ1) (1 - 
 z)^(η/ξ1 - γ/ξ - 1) Exp[λ*p*
z (-(1/ξ1) + 1/ξ)] , {z, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> ∞ > η > 0 && ∞ > γ > 
0 && ∞ > ξ > 0 && ∞ > λ > 
0 && ∞ > μ > 0 && ∞ > p > 
0 && ∞ > ξ1 > 0 && 1 >= z >= 0]
```

I am trying to integrate the above function, Mathematica tool is not any showing error. Is the above function is divergent? Could you please suggest.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1985124).

Comment: Looking at a simpler integral: this will work provided $f,g \in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and they are small.
$$e^z z^f (1-z)^g \left(1-\frac{\Gamma (a,b (z-1))-\Gamma (a,b)}{\Gamma (a)-\Gamma (a,b)}\right)$$

Comment: @flinty ,I tried to run below code ,not getting any results ,Could you suggest what is wrong ,Integrate[
 E^z (1 - z)^f z^
  g (1 - (-Gamma[a, b] + Gamma[a, b (-1 + z)])/(
    Gamma[a] - Gamma[a, b])), {z, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> f < 10 && g < 10]

Comment: This is not a convergence error because there is nothing to converge here---a symbolic integration is requested. Not every symbolic integral can be computed.

Comment: In my code above you need to replace $f,g$ with integer values.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the integral can be computed for any values of parameters. However, in one special nontrivial case of $\gamma=\xi$ the integrand takes a simpler form

```
f=(1-(-Gamma[γ/ξ,-((p λ)/ξ)]+Gamma[γ/ξ,(p (-1+z) λ)/ξ])/(Gamma[γ/ξ]-Gamma[γ/ξ,-((p λ)/ξ)])) z^(μ/ξ1) (1-z)^(η/ξ1-γ/ξ-1) Exp[λ*p*z (-(1/ξ1)+1/ξ)]/.γ->ξ//FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{(1-z)^{\frac{\eta }{\text{$\xi $1}}-2} z^{\mu /\text{$\xi $1}} \left(e^{\frac{\lambda  p}{\xi }}-e^{\frac{\lambda  p z}{\xi }}\right) e^{-\frac{\lambda  p z}{\text{$\xi $1}}}}{e^{\frac{\lambda  p}{\xi }}-1},$$

and the integral can be computed

```
Integrate[f,{z,0,1},Assumptions->∞>η>0&&∞>ξ>0&&∞>λ>0&&∞>μ>0&&∞>p>0&&∞>ξ1>0&&1>=z>=0]
```

$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\eta }{\text{$\xi $1}}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\mu +\text{$\xi $1}}{\text{$\xi $1}}\right) \left(e^{\frac{\lambda  p}{\xi }} \, _1\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{\mu +\text{$\xi $1}}{\text{$\xi $1}};\frac{\eta +\mu }{\text{$\xi $1}};-\frac{p \lambda }{\text{$\xi $1}}\right)-\, _1\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{\mu +\text{$\xi $1}}{\text{$\xi $1}};\frac{\eta +\mu }{\text{$\xi $1}};p \lambda  \left(\frac{1}{\xi }-\frac{1}{\text{$\xi $1}}\right)\right)\right)}{e^{\frac{\lambda  p}{\xi }}-1}$$ 
for  $\eta >\text{$\xi $1}$.

Comment: Thanks, the gamma and Xi have a different meaning in the model in which I am currently working. why it could the general integration does not exist, do you have any suggestions.

Comment: @Pramod_achar This is not a bug, this is not a convergence error that general integration does not exist. This is a very typical situation. Most of the integrals cannot be computed. P.S. I am wondering why you write gamma small and Xi capital, shouldn't it be "xi"?

Comment: Thanks, not noticed previously Xi, I wrote it while I need to write in Mathematica \[Xi].